# PrimeNG - column filtering and languages with tones/accents

Tags: javascript, angular, locale, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to perform filtering into columns of a table that contains data in **Greek** language.

Unfortunately the `<p-columnFilter>` component internally **does not seem to recognize the characters with tones to be the same with the same character without a tone**. For example a **vowel with a tone** (ή) **is not matched with the same vowel witout tone** (η).

Example with pictures below:

**1) Filtering using the tone ή**

[image: 1) Filtering using the tone ή]

**2) Filtering without using the tone η (which does not match with ή)**

[image: Filtering without using the tone η (which does not match with ή)]

In most filters out there on the web, characters with tone are matched with the same characters without tone and vice versa, how can I achieve the same here? Maybe if I could use the **localeCompare** function as filter function as an **attribute in the columnFilter**, but the documentation is not detailed in the table filtering section

I posted the same question in their [github repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11115) but I have not received any answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading their documentation, it looks like they don't expose their p-columnFilter component, nor is there an eventEmitter to get value changes on the input fields.

The fastest way to resolve your issue would be using their filter service and writing a custom filtering like this. (I used locale-contains library for this one):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-filterservice-demo-qv3t3k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Worked great, I overrided the default filters to match words as needed using your example! Thank you